# Capture all keystrokes on a PC and send to program (active or minimized)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keylogger

I have a javascript based Barcode Scanning application running on the browser, and it uses a cheap barcode scanner that's emulating a keyboard... My JS Script captures the emulated keystrokes and if it matches a record, performs an action.. everything works when the browser is active.. Now my challenge is for this browser based application to capture all keystrokes on the PC wherever the focus may be..

What is the best way to go about this? Any suggestions?

At the moment i'm looking to code an AutoHotkey script , but there may be better ways out there that you guys know of, so i'm wide open for some suggestions and leads.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: suggestions anyone?...

Comment: Just reread your question and I missed the part about the browser being minimized, I thought you were referring to an input without focus. Unfortunately you cannot capture events when outside of the browser as this would be a HUGE security hole allowing websites to capture data from other tabs, programs, etc... all without the users knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jQuery plugin to solve this exact problem. You can check it out @ https://github.com/ericuldall/jquery-pos

Basic code example:

```
$(document).pos();
$(document).on('scan.pos.barcode', function(event){
    var barcode = event.code;
    //do something with your barcode here
});
```

`Disclaimer:` I've currently only tested this with one barcode scanner and on barcodes that are digits only, but if you have other requirements I'd be happy to continue expanding the plugin to meet your needs.

Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks... before I dive into this though may I clarify/confirm with you that this is something that allows capture of keystrokes even if Browser is inactive/minimized? <-- this is my true problem.

Comment: It does not, which you can see in my comment on your original post. Allowing a browser to capture keystrokes (or any other data for that matter) when the browser window is not in focus would allow a website to keylog all actions taken on your computer while their site is running in a browser window. So the scope of javascript stops at edge of the browser window.

Comment: You could perhaps build a small application that runs on Mac and PC that will collect scanner input then open a web browser and pass the input in, but that's simply theoretical at this point.